# Google Cloud CDN get edge Location from logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-cdn

Currently the Google CDN has a new logging feature (https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/logging?hl=en).

In contrast to AWS's Cloudfront that contains a "x-edge-location" field in their Access Logs, I cannot determine the traffic target on google cloud.

Is there any possibility to reliably (no geoip) find out the used edge location of the specific request in Google's CDN. This would be very relevant as its closely related to all kinds of Accounting/Billing of CDN traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such logging nor response header feature in place right now, but seeing as there's an open, public [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/65263146) for that, I'm guessing it'll be just a matter of time until this becomes a reality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though the link you posted does not seem to be publicly available.

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to the party John, but I've edited the link; it should be accessible now.